# Mule RegistrationException

Tags: jaxb, mule

So this one makes me wonder. I have a Mule integration with a couple of flows in it and they all work nice. Except for the last one.
If I end that one in a file endpoint, it works as expected. But if I end it in my WS POST service.. I get an error complaining about multiple JAXB contexts.
I have multiple JAXB contexts but as said they work fine if I'm not trying to post my JSON to that REST service. 
And somehow, I can't see that my HTTP endpoint has anything to do with JAXB either so I guess it's a misguiding error?
But then, what is wrong with my HTTP endpoint, I use it as inbound in the other flows and also tried to create an entirely new one for this particular flow, but still this nagging about JAXB.

```
<http:request-config name="WS" host="127.0.0.1" port="81" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" basePath="WSService"/>
<http:request-config name="MQService" host="127.0.0.1" port="82" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" />
<mulexml:jaxb-context name="JAXB_A" packageNames="se.razorlib.SystemAProduct" doc:name="JAXB Context"/>
<mulexml:jaxb-context name="JAXB_B" packageNames="se.razorlib.SystemAPurchase" doc:name="JAXB Context"/>
<mulexml:jaxb-context name="JAXB_C" packageNames="se.razorlib.SystemAOrder" doc:name="JAXB Context"/>
<context:property-placeholder location="razorlib.properties"/>
 <flow name="ProductToSystemA">
    ....
   <http:request config-ref="WS" path="Product/REST/GetProduct/{id}/{index}" method="GET" doc:name="WS">
        <http:request-builder>
            <http:uri-param paramName="id" value="${WS.id}"/>
            <http:uri-param paramName="index" value="1"/>
        </http:request-builder>
   </http:request>   
    .....
 </flow>
<flow name="PurchaseToSystemA">
    .....
</flow>
```

.....

and this particular flow

```
    <flow name="PurchaseDeliver">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\temp\fileIn" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="FileIn"/>
   <mulexml:jaxb-xml-to-object-transformer returnClass="se.razorlib.SystemAPurchase.Header" encoding="UTF-16" jaxbContext-ref="JAXB_B" doc:name="XML to JAXB Object"/>
    <custom-transformer returnClass="java.util.List" encoding="utf-16" class="se.razorlib.Transformer.Map2ZZPurchase" doc:name="Map2ZZ"/>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer encoding="UTF-16" doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    <logger message="'Payload ' #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <http:request config-ref="WS" path="PurchaseSvc/REST/Deliver/{id}" method="POST" doc:name="WSDeliver">
        <http:request-builder>
            <http:uri-param paramName="id" value="${WS.id}"/>
        </http:request-builder>
   </http:request>
   <!--  <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\temp\fileOut" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" outputPattern="inkop2ZZ-#[function:dateStamp].json" mimeType="text/json" encoding="UTF-8"/> -->
    <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
        <logger message="Oh no!!" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\temp\fileError" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" outputPattern="error-inkop2ZZ-#[function:dateStamp].xml" mimeType="text/xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    </catch-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

The error I get is this one:

> Root Exception stack trace:
>   org.mule.api.registry.RegistrationException: More than one object of type class javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext registered but only one expected.

Regards

Comment: Your scenario seems to be strange though. But the error somehow pointing  for below answer. Check whether it works or not?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a similar scenario's,  this might be because of Multiple jaxb-context.  Resolved by placing all the packages in one Context

```
  <mulexml:jaxb-context name="JaxbContext" packageNames="se.razorlib.SystemAProduct:se.razorlib.SystemAPurchase:se.razorlib.SystemAOrder"/>
```

In flow

```
 <mulexml:jaxb-xml-to-object-transformer returnClass="se.razorlib.SystemAPurchase.Header" encoding="UTF-16" jaxbContext-ref="JaxbContext" doc:name="XML to JAXB Object"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried your method but then it complains about missing ObjectFactory, which of cause isn't missing, it's still there

Comment: Remove the return class `jaxb-xml-to-object-transformer`. Try the below code  <mulexml:jaxb-xml-to-object-transformer  jaxbContext-ref="JaxbContext" doc:name="XML to JAXB Object"/>

Comment: No luck, still complaining about the missing Objectfactory or index file.

Comment: But I noticed the "The element name {}Header has more than one mapping" error.. so at least I can try to sort out this one and get away from having a JAXB_Context defined for every package. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First I would not be surprised that the file endpoint gave no error. The file doesn't care what it gets. It just wants ones and zeros. I somewhat agree with the answer above but I think you only need to reference the package for the three Java bindings.

```
<mulexml:jaxb-context name="myJaxb" packageNames="se.razorlib"/>
```

You are defining the context for JAXB transformations. The package says it all.

Comment: But, in the log my payload are already a nice JSON string when it reach the HTTP endpoint, which have no use for a JAXB Context. So why the error in the final endpoint? It confuses me.

Comment: Why not trying this without using JAXB? I'm not sure what's happening exactly but I would try the web service post and use Dataweave (if EE) or create a Java component and implement callable to debug. I'm more comfortable if I can deal in Java. Sorry we haven't resolved this for you just yet

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll look up how to do this in pure java, feels a lot better without all the "magic".